# fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 524288000 bytes)

Tags: django, git, heroku, git-push

I am working with django. I have first tracked the staticfiles folder which is generated when we run python manage.py collectstatic {'its a copy of original static files actually"}. I don't want to track it because its increasing size of project while deploying and push in git. so i just added it in gitignore and removed from index using 'git rm -r --cached foldername'.

After it when i try to push changes its giving error.
Previously i have modified my config files to push larger files.

**Error: fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 524288000 bytes)**
I thing
My config file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    packedGitLimit = 128m
    packedGitWindowSize = 128m
[remote "origin"]
    url = 'removed for privacy '
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "developer"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/developer
[remote "heroku"]
    url = 'removed for privacy '
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/*
[pack]
  deltaCacheSize = 128m
  packSizeLimit = 128m
  windowMemory = 128m
```

Comment: What is the "it" that is giving errors?  `git push`?

Comment: yes pushing changes is giving error.